# Get difference between two Joda dates in seconds

Tags: java, android, datetime, sharedpreferences, jodatime

I am trying to use `joda` API in my app for playing with `Date` object.

In some activity i am storing `joda` datetime in `sharedpreference` using following code

```
 prefsEdit.putLong(context.getString(R.string.last_status_change_time_key) , DateTime.now().getMillis());
```

Now in some other activity, i m fetching this stored preference and calculating the difference between dates using following code

```
long lastStatusChangeTime = objSharedPref.GetAppLongPrefByKey(R.string.last_status_change_time_key);
DateTime now = DateTime.now();
DateTime dateTime = new DateTime(lastStatusChangeTime);
Seconds seconds = Seconds.secondsBetween(now, dateTime);
int n = seconds.getSeconds();
```

The code always return me values in `minus` eg `-31` , `-12` etc..

It is not calculating the difference correctly .

What is missing ??

Answer (score 1):

The declaration of `secondsBetween()` is:

```
secondsBetween(ReadableInstant start, ReadableInstant end)
```

**In order to have positive result the `start` date should be a date before the `end` date.**

It is because `secondsBetween()` doesn't return an absolute value.
In your example `dateTime` is obviously before `now`, so in order to get positive values the invocation should be:

```
Seconds seconds = Seconds.secondsBetween(dateTime, now);
```

instead of:

```
Seconds seconds = Seconds.secondsBetween(now, dateTime); // <- wrong order as `startDate` parameter is a date after `endDate` parameter
```

and your code could be:

```
long lastStatusChangeTime = objSharedPref.GetAppLongPrefByKey(R.string.last_status_change_time_key);
DateTime now = DateTime.now();
DateTime dateTime = new DateTime(lastStatusChangeTime);
Seconds seconds = Seconds.secondsBetween(dateTime, now); // <-- Here is the difference
int n = seconds.getSeconds();
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use native Java code.

```
long oldTime = Calendar.getInstance().getTime().getTime();
Thread.sleep(10*1000);
long newTime = Calendar.getInstance().getTime().getTime();

long diffInMillisecods = newTime - oldTime;
long diffInSeconds = diffInMillisecods / 1000;
```